# Using ArcGIS Online credits?

Tags: arcgis-online, pricing

I've been browsing the new ArcGIS Online credits policy, but I don't understand very much how much money this service would cost to my company.

I've read two webpages:

- http://www.esri.com/news/releases/12-2qtr/arcgis-online-will-change-how-you-think-about-mapping-and-gis.html
- http://gis-elektrika.blogspot.com.es/2012/06/arcgis-online-pricing-what-is-service.html

but I haven't drawn a conclusion.

In my company:

- GIS web traffic (with ArcGIS Server): 4 people, who use 0.2 Mbps of the bandwidth
- Vector information: 20 GB
- Raster information (satellite imagery): 100 GB

I'm trying to guess the monthly bill, but I'm not able. Any similar experience is welcome.

Comment: You can get a direct quote from ESRI too. That might be much easier than asking here.

Comment: @SonOfabox - "trying to guess monthly bill" it sounds like you are looking at the amazon cloud offering by esri. My company uses ~$750 in amazon charges. This has nothing to do with esri. I just pay my annual maintanence and use my license on the cloud.

Answer (score 3):

Review with up to date licensing and pricing info here:

http://www.georelated.com/2012/10/cloud-web-mapping-service-api-review.html

May help answer your question and v handy links inside.

Answer (score 2):

Arcgis for organizations is priced as per user packs.
See this link for [up-to-date pricing](http://www.arcgis.com/features/plans/pricing.html) posted by esri.
Service credits are used for technical support.
There are other [features](http://www.arcgis.com/features/features.html) not available in the personal account.
Use this [page to compare features of the two subscription models](http://www.esri.com/software/marketing-analytics/arcgisonline/features/comparison-table).

[The arcgis online personal account remains free with 2GB of storage space.](http://www.esri.com/software/marketing-analytics/arcgisonline/features/free-personal-account)

Comment: The "up-to-date pricing" and "compare features" links are unavailable.

Comment: updated links :)

Comment: Thank you, yes, except [that page](http://www.arcgis.com/features/plans/pricing.html) doesn't display/post the prices: it posts a telephone number.

Comment: did you scroll up? I see prices and the number below

Comment: I see "ArcGIS Online Subscription Plans<br/>A complete SaaS mapping and analytics platform<br/>Ready for ArcGIS Online?<br/>Call us to get started today.<br/>1-800-447-9778<br/>If you are outside the United States, please contact your local Esri office." May that's because I'm outside the States.

Answer (score 2):

I also found the credits/cost calculation a bit confusing, so I made a spreadsheet to help estimate it.

An ArcGIS Online subscription includes 2,500 credits per year, but I wanted to know of any additional charges if I was to exceed that limit.

I took the values from http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/credits along with the cost for additional credits (obtained from my local Esri distributor) and basically added up the credits required for operations that I need.

[image]

You can also monitor your usage after-the-fact via the Monitor Status panel in your ArcGIS Online dashboard:

[image]

This provides a dashboard interface which shows the breakdown of credit usage.

Answer (score 0):

> GIS web traffic (with ArcGIS Server): 4 people, who use 0.2 Mbps of
>   the bandwidth

I can't tell exactly what you mean by this, but you are not charged for the number of times your data is requested. You're charged for storage and premium services (routing, geocodes, geo-enrichment, premium content, etc).

> Vector information: 20 GB

Per Esri's [Service Credits Overview page](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/credits), you'll use 4,800 credits per month for vector feature services (2.4 credits per 10 MB stored per month).

> Raster information (satellite imagery): 100 GB

Per the same Service Credits Overview page, you'll use 120 credits per month for tile services storage (1.2 credits per 1 GB stored per month).

You [purchase a plan](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/purchase) based on how many users you have. The plan comes with a certain number of credits, then you pay for more credits above and beyond what the plan includes at a rate of $100 per 1,000 credits.
So if you had the lowest plan you'd spend _ per year.
$2,500 annual fee for 5 users - includes the first 2,500 credits.
$2,904 for the additional 2420 credits used in a year ($242/month).
Dividing the total $5,404 annual cost by month gives you a **monthly cost of $450.33**.

Side note: I'm assuming the 20GB of vector features and 100GB of satellite imagery are hosted in ArcGIS Online and not on your ArcGIS Server. If you are hosting the data on your server and simply sharing it via ArcGIS Online you wouldn't use all those hosting credits.

Answer (score 0):

An updated location to buy credits in batches of a 1000 if you're not on an Enterprise agreement:
https://www.esri.com/en-us/store/arcgis-online/arcgis-online-credits